# xfce4 terminal: disable individual shortcut

Tags: terminal, xfce

I would like to disable the <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>W</kbd> shortcut which closes the current terminal tab.

I am using Vim where <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd> <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>W</kbd> moves between windows of the `vim` instance. Sometimes it may happen that the <kbd>Shift</kbd> key is pressed unintentionally while trying to move to the next window. However, this immediately closes the current terminal tab with the editor session.

Can I disable <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>W</kbd> in the terminal and leaving other shortcuts untouched?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This part from the [XFCE FAQ](http://docs.xfce.org/faq):

---

- If you are running the Xfce desktop environment, enable **Editable menu accelerators** in the **[User Interface Preferences](http://docs.xfce.org/xfce/xfce4-settings/appearance#menu_and_buttons)** dialog.
- If you are running GNOME then you can enable **Editable menu accelerators** in the **Menu and Toolbars** control center dialog.
- Otherwise put the following in your `~/.gtkrc-2.0 file` (create the file if it doesn't exist):

  ```
  gtk-can-change-accels=1
  ```

When `xfsettingsd` is running you must change the setting with the Xfce GUI, not through the `~/.gtkrc-2.0` file.

---

Once that is done:

- Open `xfce4-terminal`
- Open a new tab (**Ctrl+Shift+T**) so you have two tabs open
- Move your mouse up to **File** and click to open the menu
- Move your mouse down to **Close Tab Ctrl+Shift+W** and do NOT click the mouse
- Press the **Backspace** key on your keyboard

Shortcut gone!

---

The **User Interface Preferences** plugin may not be installed and thus editing the file

```
~/.config/xfce4/terminal/accels.scm
```

may become necessary. Adding the line

```
(gtk_accel_path "<Actions>/terminal-window/close-tab" "")
```

will have disabled the shortcut after the next start of the terminal.

Comment: This doesn't work for me (running xfce4, xfsettingsd, xfce4-terminal-0.6.3), because I couldn't find the **User Interface Preferences** dialog to enable **Editable menu accelerators**, but manually editing `~/.config/xfce4/terminal/accels.scm` did.

Comment: I have added Community Wiki to my answer, please feel free to edit and add your solution as well.

Comment: This does not seem to work in recent versions (xfce4-terminal 0.8.3) Is there a new way do do this?

Comment: Can confirm this also didn't work for me, no effect whatsoever

Comment: @bli Maybe you made the same mistake as I did; I had to uncomment the line with `gtk_accel_path`, i.e. remove the semi-colon at the beginning of the line. Using the GUI didn't work for me